Mixed modal MANOVA or something else?
I am once again asking for your help. I am developing a research proposal and I am a bit confused. I have a randomized controlled trial (RCT) for testing the efficacy of a therapeutic intervention, in the following setting:

The intervention is binary (placebo and experimental).
I also have access to a binary variable serostatus (seropositive and seronegative).
There are also two dependent variables (couple satisfaction and treatment adherence).
I will also measure at 3 points in time (baseline, post-test and 6 months).

The way I thought about it is this
three independent variables (intervention group, serostatus and time) and two dependent variables (satisfaction score for each partner and self-reported treatment adherence for only one).
My question is, is it proper to use a mixed model MANOVA? And how exactly would I search for it online to give me some resources as to how I should write it in my paper (I have found several names for it and I am not sure if I am on the right track)? Thank you, I hope this makes sense.

Why do you have two DVs? Are you testing two hypotheses, or do you believe these two DVs are related in some way?

yes I believe they are related and I have 2 hypotheses

How many couples are you planning to study? And do all the key variables vary within couples?
